# HTML Element not centering even it has a width, and is a block

Tags: html, css, alignment

I searched for a long while, but all of them said to give a width, make display block, and set text-align.
I maked this for welcome card.
It also worked for the first card too.
But it doesn't work for second card Icon and text.

First one works, but second doesn't:

```
    <div class="mdl-grid" id="sub-content">
<!--First Card-->
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col main-card-medium mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <i class="sub-icon material-icons slideanim">book</i>
        <div class="mdl-card__title slideanim">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text subcontent-title">All-Inclusive</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text subcontent-title slideanim">
            This app contains all info about Champions, Summoners, Items, Runes and Masteries.
        </div>
    </div>
<!--Second Card-->
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col main-card-medium mdl-shadow--2dp">
        <i class="sub-icon material-icons slideanim">wifi_perm</i>
        <div class="mdl-card__title slideanim">
            <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text subcontent-title">Test Your Ping</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text subcontent-title slideanim">
            You can check your ping for all servers.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-card-medium {
    width: 25%;
    display: block;
}


.mdl-cell--4-col {
    margin: auto;
}

.sub-icon {
    font-size: 100px;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    color: #3f51b5;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-content {
    background: #3E4EB8;
}


.subcontent-title {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.mdl-cell--12-col {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

EDIT: Updated fiddle with both suggestions: https://jsfiddle.net/2kz7tbnu/1/

Comment: What do exactly mean? Should all `.mdl-cell` elements always kept centered, and therefore occur only once per row. Or should remaining space be divided on the outside instead of the current situation (space between)? Or something completely different?

Comment: Yes, all should be centered.

Comment: Do you mean my first guess?

Comment: Yes, book and two texts should be centered to the card.

Comment: So, all div's with a class name `sub-icon` or `subcontent-title` should have a centered content. I only saw a problem with the wifi icon, but that is probably a separate issue (https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/issues/302)

Comment: @Lemnis probably that's why, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you have a width on the card just remove the width and it will be centered

```
/*width: 25%*/
```

here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kz7tbnu/)

Comment: Thanks I will try this in a minute, since we removed the width, is there a way to make all cards width same?

Comment: It's still same (https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8t4o.png), I'm posting full html in a minute.

Comment: In my JSFiddle its fine please post code and Ill debug it

Answer (score 0):

The text in your `.material-icons` element is too long to be contained within the width you've set the parent element to. Alternatively, you could set the width on elements nested within the parent element as needed, rather than the parent element itself.

```css
.main-card-medium {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.main-card-medium > div {
    width: 25%;
    margin: auto;
}

.mdl-cell--4-col {
    margin: auto;
}

.sub-icon {
    font-size: 100px;
    margin: 30px 0px;
    color: #3f51b5;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.sub-content {
    background: #3E4EB8;
}


.subcontent-title {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.mdl-cell--12-col {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="mdl-grid" id="sub-content">
  <!--First Card-->
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col main-card-medium mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <i class="sub-icon material-icons slideanim">book</i>
    <div class="mdl-card__title slideanim">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text subcontent-title">All-Inclusive</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text subcontent-title slideanim">
      This app contains all info about Champions, Summoners, Items, Runes and Masteries.
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--Second Card-->
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col main-card-medium mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <i class="sub-icon material-icons slideanim">wifi_perm</i>
    <div class="mdl-card__title slideanim">
      <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text subcontent-title">Test Your Ping</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text subcontent-title slideanim">
      You can check your ping for all servers.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will post the full html soon, its actually icon and not too big.

Comment: Add `text-align: center` to your `.main-card-medium` element. `.material-icons` is displayed as `inline-block` so declaring `text-align: center` on its parent element would align it as intended.

Comment: It's the `letter-spacing`. If you slap in this style on `.material-icon` you'll see what I mean: `letter-spacing: -1em;`

Answer (score 0):

As @Lemnis said, It is only problem for `wifi-perm` icon. I changed it to `wifi` and it worked. And about the secondary text, I changed `width` to `90%` and now it's aligned. Thanks all!